# Where in the Catechism can one read about sins of omission?

Tags: catholicism, sin

Where in the Catechism can one read about sins of omission?
I couldn't find this term in it when I searched for it.

Answer (score 3):

The place to look is in the [online index](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_FA.HTM): within the list for O, look for *omission.*

The word is found in four paragraphs:

> [1853](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P6B.HTM#46) Sins can be distinguished according to their objects, as can every human act; or according to the virtues they oppose, by excess or defect; or according to the commandments they violate. They can also be classed according to whether they concern God, neighbor, or oneself; they can be divided into spiritual and carnal sins, or again as sins in thought, word, deed, or omission. the root of sin is in the heart of man, in his free will, according to the teaching of the Lord: "For out of the heart come evil thoughts, murder, adultery, fornication, theft, false witness, slander. These are what defile a man." But in the heart also resides charity, the source of the good and pure works, which sin wounds.

> [2277](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P7Z.HTM#1CH) Whatever its motives and means, direct euthanasia consists in putting an end to the lives of handicapped, sick, or dying persons.
> It is morally unacceptable.
>
> Thus an act or omission which, of itself or by intention, causes death in order to eliminate suffering constitutes a murder gravely contrary to the dignity of the human person and to the respect due to the living God, his Creator.
> The error of judgment into which one can fall in good faith does not change the nature of this murderous act, which must always be forbidden and excluded.

> [2284](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P80.HTM#1P) Scandal is an attitude or behavior which leads another to do evil. the person who gives scandal becomes his neighbor's tempter. He damages virtue and integrity; he may even draw his brother into spiritual death. Scandal is a grave offense if by deed or omission another is deliberately led into a grave offense.

The last, [2326](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P82.HTM#75), merely repeats the gist of 2284 in the chapter summary.

The subject might also occur in other places, but these specifically mention *omission.*